# What's an easy way to get the url in the current window minus the domain name?

Tags: javascript, string, url

My Javascript ain't so hot, so before I get into some messy string operations, I thought I'd ask:

If the current url is: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"

What's a good way to to just get: "/questions/ask" ?

Basically I want a string that matches the Url without the domain or the "http://"

Answer (score 104, accepted):

```
alert(window.location.pathname);
```

[Here's some documentation for you](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) for `window.location`.

Comment: It's not clear whether you want it, but if you potentially want `?query` and `#fragment` parts included (ie *everything* after the domain name) then add on `location.search` and `location.hash`.

Comment: @bobince - +1 Worthwhile addition. Thanks. :o)

Answer (score 67):

**ADDITIONAL ANSWER:**

window.location.pathname itself is just not enough because it doesn't include the query part, and also URN if exists:

```
Sample URI                      = "http://some.domain/path-value?query=string#testURN"
window.location.pathname result = "/path-value"
window.location.search result   = "?query=string"
pathname + search result        = "/path-value?query=string"
```

If you want to get all the values just except the domain name, you can use the following code:

```
window.location.href.replace(window.location.origin, "")
```

Or as @Maickel suggested, with a simpler syntax:

```
window.location.href.substring(window.location.origin.length);
```

This gets the following URL parts correctly:

```
http://some.domain/path-value?query=string#testURN
alert(window.location.href.replace(window.location.origin, ""))--> "/path-value?query=string#testURN"
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it's more futuristic no matter if you add query string or hash in the future.

Comment: Nice solution. Or an some what simpler syntax:
`window.location.href.substring(window.location.origin.length);`

Answer (score 5):

Use `window.location.pathname`.