# Getting the current URL directory without the domain name?

Tags: javascript, url

I am looking for some JS code that runs on page load that stores the page directory into a variable.

However the only code I can find includes the domain name too. I would like just the directory, so if I had a page URL of http://cpanen.test.com/domains/website the variable would contain "/domains/website/". Lastly, it has to be domain name independant.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's an easy way to get the url in the current window minus the domain name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955959/whats-an-easy-way-to-get-the-url-in-the-current-window-minus-the-domain-name)

Comment: var currentPathName = window.location.pathname;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to do this:

```
window.location.pathname
```

You can also substring it if you need to remove slashes, etc...

if you want additional information, definitely take a look at the `window.location` object and it will give you a lot more information, such as:

- hash
- host
- href
- origin
- pathname
- port
- protocol