# Javascript ignores # in url

Tags: javascript

I was trying to extract url after domain. According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955959/whats-an-easy-way-to-get-the-url-in-the-current-window-minus-the-domain-name) it is possible by calling `window.location.pathname`, but in my url `http://domain:host/something#random=123` it drops everything after `#` inclusive. Is there anything better out there than splitting or regex?

In code:

```
window.location.pathname("http://domain:host/something#random=123")
```

returns `/something`

**Desired behavior**:

```
window.location.unknownMethodToMe("http://domain:host/something#random=123")
```

should return `/something#random=123`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location#Examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `location.hash` which should return `#random=123`

Comment: So in order to achieve what I want I have to write something like this: window.location.pathname(url) + window.location.hash?

Comment: If 

`window.location.pathname`
returns `/something`, you should then be able to use `location.hash` to retrieve `#random=123`